# how does fscanf works with different variable types?

Tags: c, file, variables, scanf

I was looking at the MSDN documentation for [fscanf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fscanf-fscanf-l-fwscanf-fwscanf-l?view=msvc-170). I tried changing the sample code in the documentation, but it didn't work as I expected.

If, for example, I have a file "x" with the contents:

> "string" 7 3.13 'x'

After `scanf("%s", string_input)` is executed so the data `"string"` is read into `string_input`, does it go to the next in line, or to the `7` for the next read?

Next, suppose the following executes:

```
char test;
fscanf("%c" , &test)
```

Will the program jump to the `'x'` or read the `7` as its ASCII value?

Here's my rewrite of the sample code from the documentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *stream;

int main( void )
{
    long l;
    float fp,fp1;
    char s[81];
    char c,t;

    stream = fopen( "fscanf.out", "w+" );
    if( stream == NULL )
        printf( "The file fscanf.out was not opened\n" );
    else
    {
        fprintf( stream, "%s %d %c%f%ld%f%c", "a-string",48,'y', 5.15,
                 65000, 3.14159, 'x' );
        // Security caution!
        // Beware loading data from a file without confirming its size,
        // as it may lead to a buffer overrun situation.
        /* Set pointer to beginning of file: */
        fseek( stream, 0L, SEEK_SET );

        /* Read data back from file: */
        fscanf( stream, "%s", s );
        fscanf( stream, "%c", &t );
        fscanf( stream, "%c", &c );

        fscanf( stream, "%f", &fp );
        fscanf( stream, "%f", &fp1 );
        fscanf( stream, "%ld", &l );

     

        printf( "%s\n", s );
        printf("%c\n" , t);
        printf( "%ld\n", l );
        printf( "%f\n", fp );
        printf( "%c\n", c );
     
        printf("f\n",fp1);
        getchar();


        fclose( stream );
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
a-string

-858553460
8.000000
4
f
```

Why is this the output? I was expecting:

```
a-string
0
65000
5.15
y
3.14159
```

Comment: Click the white-tick next your choice of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing format specifier:

```
printf("f\n",fp1);
```

should be:

```
printf("%f\n",fp1);
```

More importantly: **check the return value of `fscanf()`**. It returns the number of successful assignments made: it should be `1` for each call here as there should be exactly one assignment per `fscanf()` call. If `fscanf()` fails, the variable is unmodified. As the variables in the code are uninitialised, if `fscanf()` fails to assign to them they will contain random values, which is the case here:

```
                            /* a-string 48 y 5.15 65000 3.14159 x */
fscanf(stream, "%s", s);    /* ^             (s is assigned "a-string") */
fscanf(stream, "%c", &t);   /*         ^     (t is assigned space)      */
fscanf(stream, "%c", &c);   /*          ^    (c is assigned 4)          */
fscanf(stream, "%f", &fp);  /*           ^   (fp is assigned 8)         */
fscanf(stream, "%f", &fp1); /*             ^ (fail: 'y' is not a float) */
fscanf(stream, "%ld", &l);  /*             ^ (fail: 'y' is not a long)  */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your write statement was

> "%s %d %c%f%ld%f%c", "a-string",48,'y', 5.15, 65000, 3.14159, 'x'

If you print the fifth argument as `%ld` then you should also pass it as `(long)65000`. But on most systems this won't make a difference. The content of the file should now look and get parsed as follows:

```
a-string 48 y5.15650003.14159x
^       ^^^
s       |c|
        t fp

s:  "a-string"
t:  ' '
l:  undefined
fp: 8
c:  '4'
fp1: undefined
```

So `s` matches the first word, up to the first space. `t` matches the space character, as `%c` won't skip leading whitespace. `c` matches the first digit of `48`, and `fp` the second digit. The `%f` for `fp1` will skip the next space, and then fail to read anything, as the character `y` cannot be read as a floatingpoint number. The `%ld` for `%l` will fail for the same reason. You should check the result of `fscanf` to detect and report such errors.